# How to return captured variable from `FnMut`

Tags: rust, closures

I have a function, `collect_n`, that returns a `Future` that repeatedly `polls` a `futures::sync::mpsc::Receiver` and collects the results into a vector, and resolves with that vector.  The problem is that it consumes the `Receiver`, so that `Receiver` can't be used again.  I'm trying to write a version that takes ownership of the `Receiver` but then returns ownership back to the caller when the returned `Future` resolves.

Here's what I wrote:

```
/// Like collect_n but returns the mpsc::Receiver it consumes so it can be reused.
pub fn collect_n_reusable<T>(
    mut rx: mpsc::Receiver<T>,
    n: usize,
) -> impl Future<Item = (mpsc::Receiver<T>, Vec<T>), Error = ()> {
    let mut events = Vec::new();

    future::poll_fn(move || {
        while events.len() < n {
            let e = try_ready!(rx.poll()).unwrap();
            events.push(e);
        }
        let ret = mem::replace(&mut events, Vec::new());
        Ok(Async::Ready((rx, ret)))
    })
}
```

This results in a compile error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `rx`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
   --> src/test_util.rs:200:26
    |
189 |     mut rx: mpsc::Receiver<T>,
    |     ------ captured outer variable
...
200 |         Ok(Async::Ready((rx, ret)))
    |                          ^^ move occurs because `rx` has type `futures::sync::mpsc::Receiver<T>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

How can I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible unless your variable is shareable like `Rc` or `Arc`, since `FnMut` can be called multiple times it is possible that your closure needs to return  the captured variable more than one. But after returning you lose the ownership of the variable so you cannot return it back, due to safety Rust doesn't let you do this.

According to your logic we know that once your `Future` is ready it will not need to be polled again, so we can create a solution without using smart pointer. Lets consider a container object like below, I've used `Option`:

```rust
use futures::sync::mpsc;
use futures::{Future, Async, try_ready};
use futures::stream::Stream;
use core::mem;

pub fn collect_n_reusable<T>(
    mut rx: mpsc::Receiver<T>,
    n: usize,
) -> impl Future<Item = (mpsc::Receiver<T>, Vec<T>), Error = ()> {
    let mut events = Vec::new();
    let mut rx = Some(rx); //wrapped with an Option 
    futures::future::poll_fn(move || {
        while events.len() < n {
            let e = try_ready!(rx.as_mut().unwrap().poll()).unwrap();//used over an Option
            events.push(e);
        }
        let ret = mem::replace(&mut events, Vec::new());

        //We took it from option and returned.
        //Careful this will panic if the return line got execute more than once.
        Ok(Async::Ready((rx.take().unwrap(), ret)))
    })
    .fuse()
}
```

Basically we captured the **container** not the **receiver**. So this made compiler happy. I used `fuse()` to make sure the closure will not be called again after returning `Async::Ready`, otherwise it would panic for further polls.

The other solution would be using `std::mem::swap` :

```rust
futures::future::poll_fn(move || {
    while events.len() < n {
        let e = try_ready!(rx.poll()).unwrap();
        events.push(e);
    }
    let mut place_holder_receiver = futures::sync::mpsc::channel(0).1; //creating object with same type to swap with actual one. 
    let ret = mem::replace(&mut events, Vec::new());
    mem::swap(&mut place_holder_receiver, &mut rx); //Swapping the actual receiver with the placeholder

    Ok(Async::Ready((place_holder_receiver, ret))) //so we can return placeholder in here
})
.fuse()
```

Simply I've swapped actual `receiver` with the `place_holder_receiver`. Since placeholder is created in `FnMut`(**Not captured**) we can return it as many time as we want, so compiler is happy again. Thanks to `fuse()` this closure will not be called after successful return, otherwise it would return the `Receiver`s with a dropped `Sender`.

**See also:**

- https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.4/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html#method.fuse

Comment: Is there reference on what would prevent Rust to have the closure be borrowed for as long as its outputs that reference it live?
(this works in stardard code, why doesn't it here?:
`struct FnMut(CapturedVar);
impl FnMut {
fn execute(&mut self) -> &mut CapturedVar {
&mut self.0
}
}
`
)