# Return a closure returning the function argument in Rust

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'm trying to a write a function, which will take an argument of type T and return a closure, which, when called, will return that argument.
How do I write that?

```rust
pub struct ParseError {}

pub type Parser<T> = Box<dyn Fn(&str) -> Result<(&str, T), ParseError>>;

pub fn pure<T: 'static>(value: T) -> Parser<T> {
    Box::new(move |input: &str| -> Result<(&str, T), ParseError> { Ok((input, value)) })
}
```

The error:

```
    Checking parsec v0.1.0 (/home/arjaz/Documents/code/rust/parsec)
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `value`, a captured variable in an `Fn` closure
  --> src/parsec.rs:16:79
   |
12 | pub fn pure<T: 'static>(value: T) -> Parser<T>
   |                         ----- captured outer variable
...
16 |     Box::new(move |input: &str| -> Result<(&str, T), ParseError> { Ok((input, value)) })
   |                                                                               ^^^^^ move occurs because `value` has type `T`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
error: could not compile `parsec`.
```

Comment: It is not working because you are returning a closure that is callable for multiple times, if you change the definition as `FnOnce` it will work but you will lose the ability of calling this closure for multiple times, please check this post for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62563511/1601571

Comment: Ok, I'll require T to implement Copy then. Thank you for clarification!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [simplified version in the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ca8274555112ebea64f9301da3c30ec5), one that avoids Box and Parser.  The function consumes `value`, and returns a closure that, when called, simply returns `value`.  Note that the closure is of type `FnOnce` (or, more precisely, is of some type based on `FnOnce`), so we can only call it once.  After the call, the memory associated with `value` belongs to the caller.

If instead we use `Fn`, then the closure can be called multiple times.  But after the first call, the closure no longer owns `value` -- it was given to the first caller as the return value -- so calling the closure a second time is not going to work.  Hence the error.  If a closure is going to return the value multiple times, then it must return a copy or clone of `value`, retaining ownership of the original for itself.  Since the function is generic over the type of `value`, `T`, you would need to constrain `T` to be `Copy` or `Clone`.