# How to collect multiple results from concurrently working for loop?

Tags: rust, rust-futures

I would like to run a function with lots of different variables

Let assume my function is :

```
async fn do_the_hard_job(my_input: u16) {
    ...
    // do the hard job that takes some time
    if my_condition {
        println!("{}", input);
    }
}
```

And I would like to run this function for many inputs; let's say my inputs are

```
inputs = stream::iter(1..=u16::MAX);
```

Since the function spends some cycles i would like to run all inputs concurrently as possible. So I could run this like

```
 inputs.for_each_concurrent(0, |input| do_the_hard_job(input))
       .await;
```

So far so good; i ran all the inputs with the function and get my output on `stdout`. But what if I want the output to be written to a certain output file ?

I can not open a file and append into it in `do_the_hard_job` function. That would mess things. I cannot add file as a parameter since the method will be run concurrently which one will borrow the mutable file.

I have tried returning the value instead of printing in the method and then collect returned vales ; like this :

```
let mut return_values:Vec<u16> = Vec::new();
inputs
    .for_each_concurrent(0, |input| async move {
        if let done = do_the_hard_job(port).await{
            if done > 0 {
                return_values.push(port);
            }
        }}).await;
```

Sadly that didn't work. What can i try to achieve my goal ?

Edit : I prepared a reproducer for the problem : https://github.com/kursatkobya/bite-sized-qualms/tree/main/concurrent-write

Comment: The bottleneck is nothing to do with the async. The method is doing a heavy task so lets say it takes around 2 second to complete a single run for a single input value.

Comment: well, i guess your `do_the_hard_job` function should return some result, otherwise you cannot retrieve the results themselves. I think there are missing parts here or your implementation is completely wrong.

Comment: I have changed that function to return things as well as i have mentioned in the latter part of the question. Yet when it comes to push results into a vector it failed. Here i have added a reproducer code : https://github.com/kursatkobya/bite-sized-qualms/tree/main/concurrent-write

Comment: It is better if you use the [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) and not github

Comment: You are facing with [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62557219/error-on-future-generator-closure-captured-variable-cannot-escape-fnmut-closu) .  Easiest solution would be wrapping the consumer with `Arc<Mutex<_>>`, please check example for [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1a804a6ab648cb1a26473224841abe0f), for the file you can use [tokio::fs](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.12.0/tokio/io/trait.AsyncWrite.html#impl-AsyncWrite) to write async values to the file

Comment: Also this post might be useful since it tells why you shouldn't block the async context, please check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48735952/why-does-futureselect-choose-the-future-with-a-longer-sleep-period-first

Comment: @ÖmerErden the solution you have provided works. Thanks a lot for the information

Comment: @KürşatKobya maybe you can write up the solution that worked for you as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine [`then`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.then) and [`collect`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.collect) to get the results:

```rust
use futures::{stream, StreamExt};
use std::{
    time::Duration,
};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let inputs = stream::iter(0..=10);

    // Finaly the one below does not work
    let output_values: Vec<u16> = inputs
        .then(|input: u16| async move {
            let result = f(input).await;
            result
        }).collect::<Vec<u16>>().await;
    println!("{:?}", output_values);

}

async fn f(input: u16) -> u16 {
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(200)).await;
    input
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2b5862caea2726e611ce9a830b27e11e)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While this solution fixes the compilation and build problems, it destroyed the concurrency. Maybe this solution can be combined with another concurrency/multi-threaded solution. The other solution given in comment  by @OmerErden worked. I can study a bit more about both solutions, thanks for providing information and giving me ideas to build a base to fight with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `zip()` to zipping two streams together

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;
use async_stream::stream;
use futures::{Future, Stream, StreamExt};
use tokio::{sync::Mutex, time::sleep};
fn foo() -> impl Stream<Item = impl Future<Output = i32>> {
    stream! {
        for i in 0..10 {
            yield async move {
                sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(1000)).await;
                i
            }
        }
    }
}
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let s = Box::pin(foo());
    let v = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::<i32>::new()));
    let z = {
        let _v = v.clone();
        s.zip(stream! {
            loop {
                yield _v.clone();
            }
        })
    };

    z.for_each_concurrent(2, |(fut, v)| async move {
        let num = fut.await;
        println!("{}", num);
        v.lock().await.push(num);
    })
    .await;
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `futures` crate and don't care about push order:

```rust
    use futures::lock::Mutex; // std::sync::Mutex not working in async
    let return_values: Vec<u16> = Vec::new();
    let return_values = Mutex::new(return_values); // wrap by Mutex
    inputs
        .for_each_concurrent(0, |input| async { // remove 'move' keyword
            if let done = do_the_hard_job(port).await {
                if done > 0 {
                    let mut return_values = return_values.lock().await; // sync
                    return_values.push(port);
                }
            }
        })
        .await;
```

Unlike other normal languages with async function, rust's async scheduler can schedule async task on multithread (depended on scheduler implement). You need to sync the resource between async tasks just like sync between multithreads.